Undo manager with multiple fields
Hello I have an application, it's very basic but has some fields for an address, so city, zip code, state etc...
I want it so the user can undo the content across multiple fields, currently the default undo only works on the field you are using. I am using NSTextFields for my fields.
I assume I need to use UndoManager but I am not sure how to implement it on my fields, my fields have ID's. Is there any documentation on how to do this, none of the fields have any functions - I just grab the data from all of the fields on one of my button events.
I don't know swift so please responsd in Obj-c so I can undertstand what needs to be done.

Documentation: NSUndoManager and Undo Architecture.

Here's a small example to get you started.

Start with the Xcode macOS App template.
Add the code below to AppDelegate.m.
Add some controls (NSTextField or another subclass of NSControl) to the window.
Connect the action of the controls to controlAction:.

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

// values before editing, the key is the identifier of the control
@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary *data;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

- (void)undoControl:(NSControl *)control oldValue:(id)oldValue newValue:(id)newValue {
    // undo
    NSString *controlID = control.identifier;
    [control setObjectValue:oldValue];
    self.data[controlID] = oldValue;
    if (control.acceptsFirstResponder)
        [self.window makeFirstResponder: control];
    // register redo
    NSLog(@"register redo %@ old:'%@' new:'%@'", controlID, oldValue, newValue);
    [[self.window.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] undoControl:control
        oldValue:newValue newValue:oldValue];
}

- (IBAction)controlAction:(NSControl *)control {
    NSString *controlID = control.identifier;
    id oldValue = self.data[controlID];
    id newValue = control.objectValue;
    if (oldValue != newValue && ![oldValue isEqual:newValue]) {
        // register undo
        NSLog(@"register undo %@ old:'%@' new:'%@'", controlID, oldValue, newValue);
        [[self.window.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] undoControl:control
            oldValue:oldValue newValue:newValue];
        self.data[controlID] = newValue;
    }
}

@end


Thank you Wileke, I will look through the code and unstand how it all works, I appeciate your time.

I have marked your answer as top and upvoted - this was unbelievbly useful, anything I searched online seemed very complicated and daughnting but your code snippet helped me see everything needed and is very easy to understand.
I am noticing one thing, when I modify a field for the first time the old value is coming up as NULL - so for things like dropdown menus when you do the final undo it takes you to a non existing blank option on the dropdown.
register undo _NS:454 old:'(null)' new:'4'
Any idea why it is coming up as null?

Is there somekind of notification available which can obtain a field or other control's value when it is selected? I am struggling to find anything online.

The 'data' property is not initialized correctly and all old values ​​are 'nil'. It should be filled with the initial values ​​of the controls. Most controls can have a delegate and/or send notifications, for example NSControlTextDidBeginEditingNotification and NSPopUpButtonWillPopUpNotification. Check the documentation of the class and delegate methods with a notification argument. Also check the superclass.

Hey Willeke, I took a look at NSControlTextDidBeginEditingNotification previously for text fields but I could only get it to fire after I had made a change so I couldn't get it to get the initial value but only the first changed value
How do I initialise data correctly to get the initial values

Another solution is getting the initial values in viewDidLoad or awakeFromNib.

I did think this but there are a good 30-40 fields, I mean I could save these in a plist or something - however in the controlAction function how would I reference the control to the correct initial value? I appeciate your help :)
I'm surprised there is no notification for like field focus - that would have been easier as I could have just grabbed the value on field focus - and then saved that as oldValue.

Ok I think I have a solution which would work, would have preferred something a bit more automated that storing each fields value - but I can do it with an array with the field Identifier and the field value.
